# How to Parent multiples objects or nodes selected to a specific group name ? (maya script)

Tags: maya

Could someone know how to Parent multiples objects or nodes selected to a specific group name ?
By a useful script :D
Or only for object have Crowd in the name automaticaly move to the correct goup name.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
// grab list of selected objects
$sl = `ls -sl`;

// the group we want to parent to
$group_name = "group1";

// now parent to the group name specified
parent -a $items $group_name;
```